# How to disable moving a window by its edge adjacent to scroll bar?

Tags: finder, customization, macos

In Mac OS X Yosemite, I find that the scroll bar is a small target for the mouse, and sometimes when I wish to scroll, I end up moving the whole window by grabbing its edge to the right of the scroll bar.  This is never the behavior I desire.

How can I disable the ability to move a window by grabbing anything other than its title bar?

Comment: Why are you trying to grab the scroll bar as it shouldn't be necessary as long as the mouse is over any scrollable area of a window it should just scroll with a scrolling motion.

Comment: @user3439894 I have those gestures turned off due to their being inadvertently invoked too often, so I need to grab the thumb to scroll the window.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same issue.

Comment: @dvallejo Nope, I still face this issue, almost two years later.

Comment: Five years later (2020) and there is still no configuration, settings, or a solution to this.

Comment: Still there.  This is a constant annoyance for me as a pen+tablet user. Gesture scrolling is not practical with the pen.  Thankfully I can still force scrollbars on, but this useless edge dragging misfeature gets in the way. all. the. time.

Answer (score 1):

I try scrolling with scroll bar because there is a scroll bar. Sometimes it's better than scrolling with mouse. (smooth scrolling)

To change, go to System Preferences: General settings -> Show scroll bars -> Always

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apple says this is by design. No use trying to complain about it. See an example post in their forum:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7491958

"It's not a bug but a deliberate design feature that was introduced a few versions of OS X ago." This reply is from years ago, already, so they do not intend to fix it at least for a while it seems.

Comment: Also known as a design bug.